# WebSocket breaks after Tomcat 7 to 8 upgrade, using NIO Connector, while having ThreadLocal in code along with Spring’s TextWebSocketHandler

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, tomcat, websocket

Websocket connection works on Spring’s WebSocket 4.1.6’s `TextWebSocketHandler`. For connection establishment we have `HandshakeInterceptor`, which in its `beforeHandshake()` method sets the user context:

```
AuthenticatedUser authUser = (AuthenticatedUser) httpServletRequest
    .getSession().getAttribute(WEB_SOCKET_USER);

UserContextHolder.setUserContext(new UserContext(authUser));
```

The `UserContextHolder` class is modeled like Spring’s `org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder` - a class to hold the current `UserContext` in thread local storage:

```
private static ThreadLocal<UserContext> userContextHolder = new InheritableThreadLocal<UserContext>(); 

public static void setUserContext(UserContext userContext) { 
    userContextHolder.set(userContext); 
    if (userContext != null) { 
        LocaleContextHolder.setLocaleContext(userContext); 
    } else { 
        LocaleContextHolder.setLocaleContext(new LocaleContext() { 
            public Locale getLocale() { 
                return UserContext.getDefaultLocale(); 
            } 
        }); 
    } 
}
```

This `UserContext` holds the thread’s authenticated `User` information for entire app, not only Spring (we also use another software, like Quartz, coexisting on this codebase on JVM, so we need to communicate between them).

Everything works okay when we run on the previous Tomcat 7 with standard BIO Connector. The problem arises with the upgrade to Tomcat 8 with the new NIO Connector being enabled by default.

When the WebSocket’s messages arrive they are processed in a call to Service methods which is validated in `@SecurityValidation` annotation, the `MethodInterceptor` checks if given thread has the User Context set:

```
AuthenticatedUser user = UserContextHolder.getUser(); 

if (user == null) { 
   throw new Exception(/* ... */); 
}
```

But it’s `null`, so `Exception` gets thrown.

We believe that the problem is in threading change after the switch from BIO to NIO Connector.

> BIO Scenario – we have one thread per one WebSocket model, so one
> Handshake sets one `UserContext` and it works on this exact thread. It
> works okay, even when there are more sockets, because i.e., when we
> have 4 different WebSockets open, there are 4 different threads
> handling them, that’s why `ThreadLocal` usage is working well.

> NIO Scenario – the Non-Blocking IO concept is for reducing the threads
> number (simplifying for our case), internally in 3rd party NIO
> Connector there is used NIO’s Selector to manage the workload on a
> single thread (with an Event Loop I guess, need to confirm). As we now
> have just one single thread to handle all the WebSockets (or at least,
> some part of them) the unexpected exception is thrown.

I’m not sure why once set `UserContext` gets nullified later, the code investigation brings us no clues, that’s why we think that might be a bug (or something).

The `UserContext`’s `ThreadLocal` being null in NIO seems to be the cause of the exception. Has anyone used `ThreadLocal` with NIO Connector? What is the best way to migrate Tomcat 7 BIO implementation to Tomcat 8 NIO implementation when using `ThreadLocal` in WebSocket communiction? Thanks!